# Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

My expo version is 42.0.0. When I run "expo build:android -t app-bundle", I get this error:

Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
• Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds'.
Couldn't publish because errors were found. (See logs above.) Please fix the errors and try again.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "XXXX",
    "slug": "XXXX",
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/XXXX.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/XXXX.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#FBDB5B"
    },
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "android": {
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "XXXX"
      },
      "package": "com.XXXX",
      "versionCode": 16,
      "permissions": [],
      "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"]
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear what answer you are looking for. Can you add some kind of question to be answered? The error message is instructing you to remove one specific property, have you tried that?

Comment: @dratenik yes I tried that and it worked. But for less size application I need to use 'enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds : true'. But I can't run "expo build:android -t app-bundle" it is causing this error

Comment: I just change SDK version 42 to 40 in app.json and i works grate right now

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, the property `enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds` was removed.. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#android. Expo wants you to use [EAS Build](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj9ubiP89j0AhUB0uAKHQ0fCS4QFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.expo.dev%2Fbuild%2Fintroduction&usg=AOvVaw26qd2UM38tQh4PxTUY07aM) for smaller bundle sizes. You might have to drop the field, otherwise your app might work in development, but then crash once you put it in PlayStore.

Personally, I also had to eject as I wasn't satisfied with the sizes EAS gave me.